# sort string array into variable type

Tags: java, sorting

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] number = new String[] {"hello", "A", "1453", "3.5", "true"};
            
    for(int i=0 ; i < number.length; i++){
        if(number[i].equals())

}
```

I'm stuck on this problem. I want to sort String number array and print on the terminal what variable type each value in the string array is. first one being a string, second char, etc..
I would appreciate feedback on how to finish this. thanks!

Comment: You could try converting them to each different type in the order double, int, boolean, char (last two order doesn't really matter). If one succeeds call it that type if they all fail call it string.

Comment: You should look up "java regex". Is this a homework assignment of some type?

Comment: @NomadMaker yes

Answer (score 0):

I would use parser methods like parseInt() and etc and do a try and error.

EDIT: you also may check the characters of a string with isLetter() and isDigit() methods

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are well.

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String[] numbers = new String[] { "hello", "A", "1453", "3.5", "true" };

            foreach (string item in numbers)
                Console.WriteLine(ParseString(item).ToString());

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static private Type ParseString(string str)
        {
            Boolean boolVal;
            Byte byteVal;
            SByte sbyteVal;
            Int32 int32Val;
            UInt32 uint32Val;
            Int16 int16Val;
            Char charVal;
            Double douVal;
            Int64 bigintVal;
            Decimal decVal;
            DateTime dateVal;

            if (Boolean.TryParse(str, out boolVal))
                return Type.GetType("System.Boolean");

            else if (Byte.TryParse(str, out byteVal))
                return Type.GetType("System.Byte");

            else if (SByte.TryParse(str, out sbyteVal))
                return Type.GetType("System.SByte");

            else if (Int32.TryParse(str, out int32Val))
                return Type.GetType("System.Int32");

            else if (UInt32.TryParse(str, out uint32Val))
                return Type.GetType("System.UInt32");

            else if (Int16.TryParse(str, out int16Val))
                return Type.GetType("System.Int16");

            else if (Char.TryParse(str, out charVal))
                return Type.GetType("System.Char");

            else if (Double.TryParse(str, out douVal))
                return Type.GetType("System.Double");

            else if (Int64.TryParse(str, out bigintVal))
                return Type.GetType("System.Int64");

            else if (Decimal.TryParse(str, out decVal))
                return Type.GetType("System.Decimal");

            else if (DateTime.TryParse(str, out dateVal))
                return Type.GetType("System.DateTime");

            else return Type.GetType("System.String");
        }
/*
// The output will be:
// System.String
// System.Char
// System.Int32
// System.Double
// System.Boolean
*/
```